# Filtering JSON in python

Tags: python, json, filter

I want to filter a json file where it only show me entries where content-type is application/json.

For now this is my code :

```
import json 

with open('rob.json', 'r', encoding="utf8") as original_file:
    data = json.load(original_file)

    for line in data:
        if line['value'] == 'application/json':
            print(line)
```

The code I have written is very basic as I am quite a beginner when it comes to scripting. However it is not working and I have an error:

```js
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I require some help on why I am having this error and whether there is a better alternative to filter a JSON file.

TIA

Comment: Can you include contents of `rob.json`?

Comment: Can you post 'rob.json' here? or, are you actually trying to parse a response from an HTTP request?

Comment: "I require some help on why I am having this error" Well, do you understand what a `TypeError` is? Do you understand what a string is? Do you understand what indices are? Do you know which line of code the error refers to? Do you see where that line of code attempts to use an index? Is the index an integer? What kind of thing is it trying to index into? Did you check? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ , and verify that the `data` looks like what you expect it to look like first. Then show it to us.

Comment: https://mcastedu-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/angele_aquilina_b42129_mcast_edu_mt/ETbGBBs7rsdDt6-uKPSeBAEBuOA1spfhAa5o19TCYJ7GPg?e=EEepHI this is the rob.json

Comment: The error is on line 'for line in data:'

Comment: Well, you are reading a JSON file from your file system and you already know that is a JSON. `content-type` is a property of HTTP header which you get when you make HTTP request. Here, I don't see a use for this. Please elaborate what you want to _"filter"_?

Comment: I want to filter all entries which content-type/value.mime-type is application/json. I'm doing some research and I need a filtered json file to move further on the research.

Comment: @AngeleAquilina What you are trying to do is not relevant as per the code you have included in this post. As I said `content-type/value.mime-type` will be used to check if the data you fetched from the internet is a JSON data or not. As per your code, you already know it's a JSON file since you are just opening it from your file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand the structure of the returned data.  It is a dictionary containing one key ("log") that is also a dictionary.  That dictionary contains an "entries" key which is a list.  That list consists of dictionaries that have keys for "request" and "response".  The "request" key has a "headers" key, which is a list of dictionaries containing "name" and "value" keys.

```
import json

with open('rob.json',encoding='utf8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Traverse the list of log entries:
for entry in data['log']['entries']:
    # Traverse the list of headers:
    for header in entry['response']['headers']:
        # Look for the appropriate name and value.
        if header['name'] == 'Content-Type' and header['value'] == 'application/json':
            # I just print the request as the response is very long...
            print(json.dumps(entry['request'],indent=2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "method": "GET",
  "url": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.map",
  "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
  "headers": [
    {
      "name": "Pragma",
      "value": "no-cache"
    },
    {
      "name": "Accept-Encoding",
      "value": "gzip,deflate,sdch"
    },
    {
      "name": "Host",
      "value": "ajax.googleapis.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Accept-Language",
      "value": "en-US,en;q=0.8"
    },
    {
      "name": "User-Agent",
      "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36"
    },
    {
      "name": "Accept",
      "value": "*/*"
    },
    {
      "name": "Referer",
      "value": "http://ericduran.github.io/chromeHAR/"
    },
    {
      "name": "Connection",
      "value": "keep-alive"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cache-Control",
      "value": "no-cache"
    }
  ],
  "queryString": [],
  "cookies": [],
  "headersSize": 412,
  "bodySize": 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me so much with this code and I understood exactly what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

with open('rob.json','r',encoding="utf8") as original_file:
    data = json.load(original_file)

    for entry in data["log"]["entries"]:
        res = entry["response"]
        for header in res["headers"]:
            if "application/json" in header["value"]:
                print(header)
```

I really don't know what you want to look for but pretty sure this code will print out the header which has value including "application/json".

Comment: File "json_filtering.py", line 7, in <module>
    content = line.get("value",None)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: I'm getting the above error. I posted the rob.json in the above comment

Comment: @AngeleAquilina, I guess you need to understand the data type loaded from a JSON file eventually is a dict. So, you just need to walk through the key/value in dict.